# Word Embedding Relations

Tags: numpy, matrix, word2vec, algebra, word-embedding

I want to learn more about the algebra function I can perform over the word embedding vectors. I know that by cosine similarity I can get the most similar word. But I need to do one more level of inference and get the relations below:

The relation of X1 to X2 is like relation of X3 to X4.

As and example I can say the relation of princess to prince is like women to men. I have X1 to X3 and my problem is how efficiently I can figure out what X4 can be. I tried cosine to absolute difference of vectors but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at exactly how the original Google-released `word2vec` code solves analogies in its `word-analogy.c` code:

https://github.com/tmikolov/word2vec/blob/master/word-analogy.c

If you're more familiar with Python, you can look how the gensim Word2Vec implementation tests analogies, in its `accuracy()` method, by reading the analogy "a:b :: c:expected" from the `questions-words.txt` file (as provided in the original Google word2vec package), then using `b` and `c` as positive (added) examples, and `a` as a negative example (subtracted), to then find words near the resulting vector:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/5f630816f8cde46c8408244fb9d3bdf7359ae4c2/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L697

The operation of the used `most_similar()` function, which accepts multiple `positive` and `negative` examples before returning a list of closest vectors, is seen at:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/5f630816f8cde46c8408244fb9d3bdf7359ae4c2/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L290